# Website drop down menus not working in windows chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

http://www.babyblooms.co.uk/ has drop down menus on mouse over on main navigation menus.

I can not see the drop down menus on mouse over in Chrome [51.0.2704.106m] although I can see those in Firefox / IE / Edge. Windows 10 is my OS.

I have tried by reinstalling the chrome.

Does anyone know what could be the reason?

Thanks

Comment: Its working fine in chrome, may try to clear browser cache or as @George told are you blocking JavaScript...

Comment: I did try by clearing the cache. But same issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you blocking JavaScript?

It's working perfectly for me, Chrome and Windows 10.

Comment: No. Javascripts are enabled. I checked in multiple places and it seems working fine for others.